# Resizing a GeoTIFF to a specific zoom level

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, tiles, zoom

Say I have a bunch of GeoTIFFs that are very high resolution. Like they could be used with a zoom level of 25, without interpolation, if you created tile layers using `gdal2tiles`. The max zoom level my application supports, vis-a-vis `gdal2tiles`-generated tile layers, is 18 so the GeoTIFFs (which will ultimately be converted to tile layers) being as high resolution as they are serves no point.

Is there a way to resize them to whatever resolution they'd need to be to support a max zoom level of 18?

I mean, I can resize them in Photoshop, I suppose, but I wouldn't know what to resize them to. Maybe I could copy (using a combination of listgeo and geotifcp) the GIS data from a high res GeoTIFF to a lower res one spanning the same area but IDK.

Comment: Photoshop destroys georeference in GeoTIFF. I would suggest GDAL_Translate https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html with the -outsize parameter to specify either a percentage or number of rows and columns; also -r parameter for resampling method to suit your data.

Comment: @MichaelStimson - Photoshop's destroying of the GIS data is why I proposed listgeo / geotifcp but, you're right, gdal_translate would be easier. But even with gdal_translate, I'm still having to guess at the percentage. Like what percentage would I need to use to reduce zoom level 25 to zoom level 18? I could brute force it to find the optimal percentage or number of rows / cols. I wouldn't want it to be too low res but neither would I want it to be needlessly high res. But I'd prefer it if I didn't have to brute force.

Comment: I'm unsure of what your zoom levels relate to; if you can calculate the number of physical pixels on screen (screen space) and then the corresponding number of cells in the raster (world space) that should be enough information to calculate the percentage of pixels required to match the maximum zoom.

Comment: @MichaelStimson - the zoom levels I'm referring to are the same ones that the `--zoom` parameter of `gdal2tiles` uses. https://developers.arcgis.com/documentation/mapping-apis-and-services/reference/zoom-levels-and-scale/ seems to elaborate. They're definitely not "my" zoom levels. And as for the number of cells in the raster...  well how do I do that? I mean I guess I could stitch together all the tiles that `gdal2tiles` generated at the various zoom levels to calculate the percentages but that's an _awful_ lot of work. Honestly, brute forcing would be less work than that.

Comment: I see the problem, how to know the size of a pixel on screen if you don't know the monitor's dimensions and resolution. The slider in that link says zoom 18 for raster layers is 1:2256.994353, that's about as far as I can help (or not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gdal2tiles utility supports whatever tiling schemas ("profiles" https://gdal.org/programs/gdal2tiles.html#cmdoption-gdal2tiles-p) and thus zoom level 18 can really mean whatever resolution. However, the default tiling schema is the Google maps compatible one. You can check the corresponding pixel sizes for example from the table at https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Zoom_levels. The pixel size of Z18 is 0.597 meters. So you can resample your source imagery to the same resolution or slightly better.

```
gdal_translate -tr 0.55 0.55 <other parameters> input.tif output.tif
```